# randomForest did not predict serial samples

Tags: r, random-forest

I have data.frame `TC`, with 17744 observations of 13 variables. The last variable is target: a `Factor w/ 2 levels "0", "1"`.

I do:

```
n.col <- ncol(TC)

x.train.or <- TC[1:12000, -n.col]
y.train.or <- TC[1:12000, n.col]
x.test.or <- TC[12000:17000, -n.col]
y.test.or <- TC[12000:17000, n.col]
rf.or <- randomForest(y=y.train.or, x=x.train.or, ntree=500, mtry=5, 
                      importance=TRUE, keep.forest=TRUE,
                      na.action=na.roughfix, replace=FALSE)
pr.or <- predict(rf.or, x.test.or)
table(y.test.or, pr.or, dnn=c("Actual", "Predicted"))

#       Predicted
# Actual    0      1
#      0    2424  780
#      1    1056  741
```

Very bad result.

Then I repeat the model fitting with a random sample:

```
set.seed <- 123
t.t <- holdout(TC[, n.col], ratio=3/5, mode = "random")
x.train.r <- TC[t.t$tr, - (n.col)]
y.train.r <- TC[t.t$tr, (n.col)] 
x.test.r <- TC[t.t$ts, - (n.col)]
rf.r <- randomForest(y=y.train.r, x=x.train.r, ntree=500, mtry=5,
                     importance=TRUE,  keep.forest=TRUE,    
                     na.action=na.roughfix, replace=FALSE)
pr.r <- predict(rf.r, x.test.r)
table(y.test.r, pr.r, dnn=c("Actual", "Predicted"))

#         Predicted
# Actual    0      1
# 0         4274  215
# 1         353   2257
```

Very good result but depended on a way of formation of sample of an one data set.
Problem which I solves assumed only serial sample.

Please, help me!

Answer to questions:
(1)Certainly I do:

```
library(randomForest)
library(rminer)
```

(3) I repeat with:

```
n.col           <-  ncol(TC)
x.train.or      <-  TC[1:12000, -n.col]
y.train.or      <-  TC[1:12000, n.col]
x.test.or       <-  TC[12001:17000, -n.col]
y.test.or       <-  TC[12001:17000, n.col]
```

and receiving the same awful result

```
      Predicted
Actual    0    1
     0 2413  790
     1 1049  748
```

(4)There could be a problem in it? Some variables are random on [1:17000], but not random on [1:100]
(I had no rights to drawings).

What to do in that case?

Comment: What is your question? A couple of comments: (1) please include `library` calls (i.e. `library(randomForest)` and `library(rminer)`). (2) You haven't included code for how you created `y.test.r` (although it's obvious how it _should_ be created. (3) I assume you didn't intend to include obs. 12000 in your test dataset since you are including it in your training set. (4) The order of the rows of `TC` is probably not random (i.e. the relationship between `y` and `x` for the first 12000 obs is not representative of that for the next 5000 obs).

Comment: I correcting a question

Answer (score 0):

First, it's going to be a little difficult to answer without knowing the state of the data. Sometimes you can be including your test set in your train set if observations repeat themselves in some sort of manner.

One of the best ways to validate your results is through using some sort of cross-validation technique paying heed to making sure you completely separate your test and train set. Below is a good video to watch on that.

http://vimeo.com/75432414